# jQuery: Display value of a field in another field at .keypress() doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I have a field 1 and I want to show the value of this field 1 in another field 2.

When I insert the first letter in field 1, for example "G" nothing happes in field 2.
But when I insert the second letter for example "Go", in field 2 only the letter "G" is shown.
I tried .keypress() and .keydown(), but without success. Any ides or help?? Here is my code:

```
$("#field1").keypress(function() {
    var val = $("#field1").val().toLowerCase();
    $("#field2").val(val);
    });
```

Comment: Use `.keyup(...)` - it is fired *after* the value is modified. `keydown` and `keypress` are fired *before* the value is modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use onkeyup

```
$("#field1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $("#field1").val().toLowerCase();
    $("#field2").val(val);
    });
```

to get the required result

check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ee4dM/)

edit : FYI

Its always prefer not to use keypress event as this event isn't covered by any official specification its behavior differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Please try keyup event

```
 $("#field1").keyup(function() {
    var val = $("#field1").val().toLowerCase();
    $("#field2").val(val);
 });
```